# "Женщина-телеграфист", но женщина - почтово-телеграфный чиновник"?

Tags: дефис-тире

Насколько я понимаю, "женщина-телеграфист" пишется через дефис, правильно? Но как пишется "женщина - почтово-телеграфный чиновник", через тире и с пробелами? А "женщины - служащие почты и телеграфа"?
(Для определенной эпохи такого рода определения их профессии были более привычными, чем "телеграфистка".)

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что тут нужно тире, выделенное пробелами.

Нашла релевантный, на мой взгляд, пример: "Человек — швейцарский нож".

Название этого фильма пишется через тире, в отличие от подобных, но односложных словосочетаний, таких как "человек-паук" или "женщина-кошка".